# HTTP handlers in IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode

Tags: iis-6, httphandler

I'm currently struggling with httphandlers in IIS.
I'm developing a website in .NET4 in VS2010 and Cassini. In this website, i have a gallery, whose pictures are loaded through my handler.
For example http://mywebsite.com/Gallery/123/Pic1.jpg
My HTTP Handler gets the id 123 and returns the picture from the database (simplified).

So, everything works fine in Cassini (VS integrated webserver) and in IIS7 in "integrated mode". Pictures are loaded like they should.

But I have to deploy this site on a shared hoster, who is using IIS6.

After many searching and own logging, I found out, the the request isn't routed to my handler, and so I get a 404 from IIS.

My definition which is enough for IIS7 integrated mode:

```
<system.web>
   <handlers>
       <add verb="*" path="Gallery/*/*" type="[coorect Type spec]" />
   </handlers>
</system.web>
```

For IIS7 in classic mode I had to add

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="ImageHandler" verb="*" path="Galler</*/*" type="[type]" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="c:\windows\Microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll"/>
    </handlers
</system.webServer>
```

This last config only works whith the stuff in the module and scriptprocessor attributes...

But this config doesn't work in IIS6....

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that IIS6 typically decides what ISAPI handler to pass the request to by using the file extension. So it sees `.jpg` and tries to serve a static file from that path. This is also what IIS7 refers to as classic mode. And you'll note you are referencing aspnet_isapi.dll in your configuration because it needs to be told what should handle this. Once you've passed it into aspnet_isapi, the asp.net http handling pipeline kicks in and you can execute your handler.

The easiest fix would be to find a host that supports IIS7. Failing that, you could see if they have any url rewriting options. With that, you could rewrite things so that you append an .ashx on the url, which will let IIS6 grab it and put it into the asp.net pipeline and your handler would fire. You could also see if they allow wildcard mappings, but that is a very tall order for most shared hosts.